# Infinite loop with React-Redux and Navigation Experimental

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have an infinite loop that seems to be occurring when I use react-redux. I use Navigation Experimental which loads connectRouteScreen as the scene to be rendered through NavigationCardStack. I'm using RN 0.30. But also could reproduce this in 0.31-rc.0

```
    [...]
    Use Navigation Experimental to transition and load connectRouteScreen as a Scene

    export default function connectRouteScreen(Scene, sceneProps){

      class RouteScreen extends React.Component{

        [...]

        render() {
          const { navigator, pathVariables } = this.props;

          return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Scene
                navigator={navigator}
              {...pathVariables.toJS()}
                />
                </View>);
        }
      }

        RouteScreen.propTypes = {...RouteScreenPropTypes};

        const routeScreenProperties = extractSceneRendererProps(sceneProps);

    /*return                <Scene
                navigator={routeScreenProperties.navigator}
              {...routeScreenProperties.pathVariables.toJS()}
                />;
    */

      return <RouteScreen
            {...routeScreenProperties}
        />;

    }
```

LoadingScreen is loaded as "Scene".

```
    @connect(
      () => {return {}},
      (dispatch) => {
        return {
          loginActions: bindActionCreators(loginActions, dispatch),
        }
      })
    export default class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
      }

      shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
        return false;
      }

      componentDidMount(){

        const { navigator } = this.props;

        this.props.loginActions.executeLoginFlow();

      }

        render() {
        const Animatable = require('react-native-animatable');
            return (
          <Animatable.View
            animation="pulse"
            easing="ease-out"
            iterationCount="infinite"
            style={localStyle.container}>
            <Icon name="logo" style={localStyle.iconStyle} size={150}/>
          </Animatable.View>
            );
        }

    };
```

So, If I return the Scene directly instead of RouteScreen, no problem.
If I remove the @connect syntax and escape this.props.loginActions..., no problem.
If I return RouteScreen and remove everything it does and just return the Scene => infinite loop.

Does anybody have any suggestions how to deal with this?

Comment: What's your `this.props.loginActions.executeLoginFlow()` doing? Are you sure you are not pushing `LoadingScreen` again as a result of that which causes it to be constantly pushed all over again?

Comment: Thx for the reply. Execute login flow is loading cookies trying to login etc. If it fails, login page. If it succeeds account page.  The loop occurs either way. I refactoring the code to have routescreen just process the websocket subscriptions and moved all the header stuff back into the navigation container. No joy. But it does suggest the websocket subscriptions are triggering the endless loop